# Identifying difference in date granularity for pandas datetime series

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have tables with different datetime formats. Given two tables the goal is to identify the format with looser granularity. The function would identify the table of smallest granularity, output this table and granularity level.

Something like this:

```
def smallest_granularity(s1, s2):
  ...
return ("seconds" or "minutes" or "hours" or "days" or "months"), s2
```

For example for

```
t1

datetime  | v1
2014-01-01| 3
2015-02-01| 4
2011-11-11| 2

t2

datetime           | v2
2010-01-07 01:00:00| 3
2008-01-11 03:20:20| 4
2019-03-03 01:04:20| 2
```

the output would be `"day", t1"` since `t1` can only differentiate dates.

for

```
t1

datetime        | v1
2014-01-01 01:00| 3
2015-02-01 05:00| 4
2011-11-11 02:35| 2

t2

datetime           | v2
2010-01-07 01:00:00| 3
2008-01-11 03:20:20| 4
2019-03-03 01:04:20| 2
```

Here the output is `"minutes", t1"` since `t1` can only differentiate up to a minute.

Is there any neat way to do it without dirty parsing?

Comment: you can do like calculate difference between two dates,according you can parse data

Comment: @AMi but difference does not give granularity...  same formats can have large difference between dates right